# "ACK" character in XML causes subsequent fields not to be extracted (Python)

Tags: python, xml, string, lxml, control-characters

I'm using lxml to parse a XML file in python. One of the files has a field that contains an "ACK" character. All subsequent fields cannot be extracted. How can I skip this field if it contains non-standard characters like "ACK" and continue to extract the remaining fields?

```
<layer1>
    <layer2>
        <layer3>
            <content><![CDATA[free-string ^F]]></content>
            <field1>10</field1>
            <field2>hello</field2>
        </layer3>
    </layer2>
</layer1>
```

What I have is (ETA to show more of the code):

```
import lxml.etree as ET
try:
    try:
        coding = 'utf-8'
        parsing = ET.XMLParser(encoding=coding, recover=True)
        tree = ET.parser(file, parser=parser)
    except:
        try:
            coding = 'cp874'
            parsing = ET.XMLParser(encoding=coding, recover=True)
            tree = ET.parser(file, parser=parser)
        except:
            try:
                coding = 'cp1252'
                parsing = ET.XMLParser(encoding=coding, recover=True)
                tree = ET.parser(file, parser=parser)
            except:
                coding = 'iso-8859-1'
                parsing = ET.XMLParser(encoding=coding, recover=True)
                tree = ET.parser(file, parser=parser)

    node = tree.find('.//layer1/layer2/layer3/content')
    if node is not None and node.text is not None:
        content = node.text
    field1_node = tree.find('.//layer1/layer2/layer3/field1')
    field1 = field1_node.text
    field2_node = tree.find('.//layer1/layer2/layer3/field2')
    field2 = field2_node.text
except:
    print "Cannot parse file"
```

When the extraction for `content` failed, extraction for `field1` and `field2` also failed (though all fields before `content` can be extracted successfully.

How do I handle such `content`?

Comment: The Unicode character U+0006 (ACKNOWLEDGE) is not allowed in XML 1.0 documents. How do you manage to parse the file? Are you using lxml's `recover` option? Please show your complete code.

Comment: I added the part where I tried different encodings and the `recover` option to my post.

Comment: `ET.parser` should be `ET.parse`, right? Please ensure that the code in the question  runs. In any case, I think the  problem has to be handled by removing/replacing the offending character before parsing is attempted. Your input is ill-formed and a conformant XML parser is correct in rejecting it. Trying different encodings won't help. The `recover=True` option can sometimes help when the input is broken, but it won't fix everything.